# Facebook share logo cache issue

Tags: facebook, share

I am having a problem on facebook share as its not showing the logo. Initially I have added a relatively larger image. Its not showing on share logo. but when I inspect it show hidden logo of my site. Then I have added a new logo like this-

> <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.deliverybusiness.biz/images/db.jpg" />
>
> <link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="http://www.deliverybusiness.biz/images/db.jpg"/>
>
> SITE URL : http://www.deliverybusiness.biz/

but its showing older logo in facebook cache.

Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing correctly for me:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.deliverybusiness.biz%2F

Maybe you didn't lint (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) the page after changing your og tags?  Or you didn't wait the 24 hour cache to expire?